# Visual Studio 2012 Load test not detecting unit tests when attempting to add them to a scenario

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 is not detecting any unit tests (in a single .cs file) when attempting to add them to a load test scenario.

I have tried to follow the steps in the following article without success:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff355993.aspx

I have the file containing the unit tests in the load test project.  I have also tried putting the file in a different Unit Test project (C#) under the same solution.  The load test wizard always reports "There are no tests available to pick" after I add a single black Web Test to the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is simple.  The unit test project must be built BEFORE you can add the individual unit tests to the load test scenario.